# Including files in ExtendedScripts Adobe

Tags: adobe, adobe-indesign

I know that we can include related file with   *#include "filepath"* . However, I want to create the file path on runtime rather than hard coding it. Passing the file path as string is not working  *I/O error* . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

So you might choose $.evalFile ( somePath )

like var myBaseUri = Folder.userData //(for exemple )
$.evalFile ( File ( myBaseUri+"/myLib.jsx" ) );

Comment: Thanks for helping, I have tried that too. I'm trying to structure my code w.r.t Common.js standard. So I can move away from #include to require("file"). I'm doing it, by creating require() as global function and If I use $.evalFile I can't get the script to get loaded in the global space (as the returned values will be in function scope). app.doScript cannot be used on the same grounds.

Comment: I see. But why would you enclose your external file within a function scope if you intend to use it globally ? Why don't you just load the file at the global level at start ?

Comment: I'm trying to extend jasmine for extended scripts. Hence I want a function to evaluate and load JSX files to global scope.